# Storybook: event does not show in the action panel

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm trying to create the `click` event on my storybook, but It doesn't matter what I do the event does not appear in the Action panel.

This is my story:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BackButton } from 'components/back-button';

export default {
  title: 'Components/BackButton',
  component: BackButton,
  argTypes: {
    onClick: {
      action: 'clicked',
    }
  }
};

const Template = (args) => <BackButton {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  onClick: {
    action: 'clicked',
  },
};
```

This is my component:

```
...

export const BackButton = ({ handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={styles['back-button']}
      viewBox="0 0 42 42"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
        <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="21" strokeWidth="2.07" />
        <path
          d="M16.95 21.34l7.3-7.3-1.07-1.08-8.38 8.38 8.38 8.37 1.07-1.05-7.3-7.3zM21 42C9.4 42 0 32.6 0 21S9.4 0 21 0s21 9.4 21 21-9.4 21-21 21z"
          fillRule="evenodd"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};
```

I've followed the instructions on https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/actions
and the only way I've managed to make it work was doing like:

```
//storybook
...
export default {
  title: 'Components/BackButton',
  component: BackButton,
  parameters: {
    actions: {
      handles: ['click'],
    },
  },
};
```

but then I get a console warning saying that actions handles is deprecated.

package.json :

```
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.14",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.14",
    "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.1.14",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.14",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.1.14",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.14",
```

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
argTypes: {
    # onClick: {  <== changes to
    handleClick: {
      action: 'clicked',
    }
  }
```

'onClick' is a sample of handler name by props defined in BackButton

Not the event name of the DOM element.

The storybook document does not separate these parts, which is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**Story:**

```
export default {
    title: "UI/Atoms/Button",
    component: Button,
    argTypes: { handleClick: { action: "clicked" } },
    args: {
       text: "Button"
    }
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Button>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof CUIButton> = args => <CUIButton {...args} />;

export const Button = Template.bind({});
Button.args = {
 color: "primary",
 size: "small",
 disabled: false
};
```

**Component:**

```
interface IProps {
    color: "primary" | "secondary" | "danger" | "success";
    size: SizeType;
    text: string;
    disabled: boolean;
    handleClick: () => void;
}

const Button: FunctionComponent<IProps> = (props: IProps) => {

 return (
   <Button className={props.color} size={props.size} disabled={props.disabled ?? false} onClick={props.handleClick}>
    {props.text}
  </Button>
);
};

export default Button;
```

make sure "@storybook/addon-actions" is in your addons list in main.js file.